# spring boot query to get the maximum value alone from a field in an array of subdocument

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregate-functions

```json
{
   "_id":"1",
   "name":"Elon musk",
   "created_by":"alien",
   "versions":[
      {
         "version":1,
         "active":true,
         "group":"ALL",
      },
      {
         "version":2,
         "active":false,
         "group":"ALL",
      }
   ]
  }
```

I need a query which returns the maximum value of `versions.version` which is 2

```java
val query = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.group("version").max("versions.version").as("maximum"),
            project("maximum").and("version").previousOperation())

val groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(query, test::class.java, sample::class.java)

for (results in groupResults){
    println(results.maximum)
}
```

I tried above but it is returning only 1 but I'm expecting 2
and also is there a query which I can use in `@Query`
need help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

this just return max version value you could customise project to get another fields

```
Arrays.asList(new Document("$match", 
    new Document("name", "Elon musk")), 
    new Document("$unwind", 
    new Document("path", "$versions")), 
    new Document("$sort", 
    new Document("versions.version", -1L)), 
    new Document("$limit", 1L), 
    new Document("$project", 
    new Document("version", "$versions.version")
            .append("_id", 0L)))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Can we use this in Spring boot?  just want to confirm or is there a way to do this via Aggregation.newAggregation () as I did above

Comment: No problem thanks for the response this should help me later !! I will save it